# MaxScale no Slave State set

Tags: docker-compose, mariadb, database-replication, maxscale

We want to use MaxScale and two MariaDB databases with docker-compose.

We have the problem that we do not achieve replication of the database via maxscale.
Write permissions are available via MaxScale on both databases. Via the command `maxscale list servers` in the maxscale container, we see both servers. The first server has the states `Master, Running` and the second server has only the state `Running`.

My `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3'
services:

  # Application
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/project
    volumes:
      - ./project:/var/www/project
      - ./php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    links:
      - database:database
    environment:
      - "DATABASE_HOST=database"
      - "DATABASE_PORT=4006"

  # Web server
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./nginx-logs:/var/log/nginx
      # Inherit from app container
      - ./project:/var/www/project
      - ./php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:8021:80
    links:
      - app:app

  # Database
  database:
    image: mariadb:latest
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./database-config:/etc/mysql/
    command: mysqld --log-bin=mariadb-bin --binlog-format=ROW --server-id=3001 --log-slave-updates
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secretDummyPassword"
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=database"
      - "MYSQL_USER=database"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=secretDummyPassword"
      - "skip-networking=0"

  #Max Scale
  maxscale:
    image: mariadb/maxscale:6.2.3
    depends_on:
      - database
    volumes:
      - ./maxscale.cnf:/etc/maxscale.cnf
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:4006:4006 # readwrite port
      - 0.0.0.0:4008:4008 # readonly port
      - 0.0.0.0:8989:8989 # REST API port
    links:
      - database:database

volumes:
  app: {}
```

My `maxscale.cnf`:

```
[maxscale]
threads=auto

[MariaDB-Monitor]
type=monitor
module=mariadbmon
servers=server1,server2
user=database
password=secretDummyPassword
auto_failover=true
auto_rejoin=true
enforce_read_only_slaves=1

[Read-Write-Service]
type=service
router=readwritesplit
servers=server1,server2
user=database
password=secretDummyPassword
master_failure_mode=fail_on_write

[Read-Write-Listener]
type=listener
service=Read-Write-Service
protocol=MariaDBClient
port=4006

[server1]
type=server
address=195.XXX.123.22
port=3306
protocol=MariaDBBackend

[server2]
type=server
address=142.XXX.186.188
port=3306
protocol=MariaDBBackend
```

Comment: Your `docker-compose.yml` only has one database and the database addresses in the MaxScale configuration do not use hostnames and instead use hard-coded IP addresses. Is your intention to have MaxScale use the database servers started up by docker-compose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't configured the replication manually, you can use the following command inside the Maxscale container to set up replication between the servers:

```
maxctrl call command mariadbmon reset-replication MariaDB-Monitor server1
```

This causes all other servers configured for the `MariaDB-Monitor` to start replicating from `server1`.

**Note**: this command resets the GTID positions so it should not be used on a live system. If you are using a live system, use the [`CHANGE MASTER TO`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/change-master-to/) command with the correct GTID coordinates. It won't touch the data but you'll lose the history (it does a [`RESET MASTER`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reset-master/)).

---

If you want the replication to be configured automatically when the container is first started, you can mount a file with SQL commands in it at `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` and MariaDB will execute them during startup. This is probably a better solution for automated systems and it is quite convenient for a test setup.